# Visual Studio Code: Copying files without breaking import paths

Tags: javascript, reactjs, visual-studio-code, plugins, import

How can I copy files from one directory to another in Visual Studio Code, without breaking the import paths? In other words, are there any plugins or tools available for readjusting the relative paths in my imports?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Go to your - file -> preference -> settings -> search for `update Imports on file move` -> change it to `always` and reload .

Comment: It's always by default on my Visual Studio Code. But when I copy files react complains that  it cannot find my files

Comment: then make a copy in the same directory (`filenameX.js`), move this file and remove the `X`

Answer (score 0):

As @rioV8 pointed out, import paths get automatically rewrittenwork fine if you make a copy of your file in the same directory and move it to the destination folder. If it doesn't work,

Go to your - file -> preference -> settings -> search for update Imports on file move -> change it to always and reload.

Thank you @Shyam and @rioV8

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem in React + Vite project.
Turns out the problem was caused by aliases I had configured in Vite config.

```
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [react()],
      alias: [
      { find: "@", replacement: path.resolve(__dirname, "src") },
         
    ],
  },
 
});
```

So to make it work I had to add `jsconfig.json` file in project root:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "ES6",
        "baseUrl": ".",
        "paths": {
            "@/*": ["src/*"]
      }
    },
    "exclude": [
        "node_modules",
        "**/node_modules/*"
    ]
}
```

With this file vscode is updating moved imports without problem.